# python list.append screws up the dictionary entries (only last entry is added in each index)

Tags: python-2.7

I have this piece of code and individually the dictionary looks fine, how ever when appended to a list, the list only shows last entry

```
def readExcel(fInputFile="", sheetname=""):

    mywb = xlrd.open_workbook(vInputFile, on_demand=True)
    sheet_names = mywb.sheet_names()
    mysheet = mywb.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])
    for row_idx in range(1,mysheet.nrows):
        for col_idx in range(mysheet.ncols):
            cell = mysheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx)
            hdr = mysheet.cell(0,col_idx)
            init_list(myl,str(hdr.value),str(cell.value))
        if testmethod==NOLOAD:
            mpt_noload_execute(myl)
        else:
            myll.append(myl)
            print("myll after each row", myll[row_idx-1]['uname'])

    for j in range(len(myll)):
        print("myll after file reading", myll[j]['uname'])
```

==============================

Execution and Results:

```
>python mpt_login_test_driver.py

('myll after each row', 'autotest01')
('myll after each row', 'autotest02')
('myll after each row', 'autotest03')
('myll after file reading', 'autotest03')   <=== error
('myll after file reading', 'autotest03')  <=== error
('myll after file reading', 'autotest03')
```

Comment: How do you get that error message? What is my11?

Comment: I think it's a short form of "**My L**inked **L**ist" (myll), similar to "**My W**ork**B**ook" (mywb),  "**My** Spread**sheet**" (mysheet), "**My L**ist" (myl).

Comment: It isn't defined anywhere in the page. It looks like he is re-using myl instead of using a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a new dictionary each iteration for myl. Otherwise you are just modifying the same one. Eg.

```
def readExcel(fInputFile="", sheetname=""):

    mywb = xlrd.open_workbook(vInputFile, on_demand=True)
    sheet_names = mywb.sheet_names()
    mysheet = mywb.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])
    for row_idx in range(1,mysheet.nrows):
        myl={}
        for col_idx in range(mysheet.ncols):
            cell = mysheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx)
            hdr = mysheet.cell(0,col_idx)
            init_list(myl,str(hdr.value),str(cell.value))
        if testmethod==NOLOAD:
            mpt_noload_execute(myl)
        else:
            myll.append(myl)
            print("myll after each row", myll[row_idx-1]['uname'])

    for j in range(len(myll)):
        print("myll after file reading", myll[j]['uname'])
```

Now myll will have a *new* dict appended and not just modify the old one.

Comment: Thanks matt, that was the issue, thank you. I thought once myl is appended to myll, i could re-purpose it, but looks like its added to myll as a reference point  .. creating new dictionary at every row loop solved that.